A simple update query to a table in my database is taking after selecting 1 record is taking more than 1 mintute
This query is taking more than 90 seconds
UPDATE `tableA`
SET
    `bill_no` = NULL
WHERE 
`tableA`.`payment_no` = 'S00005303';

how to find the cause of slowness
I checked show processlist; and there are no other queries running at the same time.

The cause of slow performance you are experiencing could be caused by a number of things, which includes:

Your tableA table is very large, and MySQL is scanning the entire table to find the one row with a payment number of S00005303
There happened to be a large number of other queries/processes executing on MySQL when you ran the update.  Due to limited bandwidth, MySQL took a long time to complete the update.

If your application/use case would involve running this update often, you could try adding the following index:
CREATE INDEX idx ON tableA (payment_no);

This index, if used, would allow MySQL to rapidly find any records with a certain payment number, and make the update.  To check if the index would be used, run:
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE payment_no = 'S00005303';

